# Python: Sum part of a list

Tags: python, list, sum

Given a list, how can I find sums of part of the list? For example:

```
a = [2,5,4,6,8]
sum(a) = 25
```

I want to find out if a part of the list sums up to a certain number.
The list part should have a certain length. This is my goal:

```
ex_list = [2,5,4,6,8]
dif_list = partsum(ex_list, 3)
print(dif_list) ==> [11, 13, 15, 12, 14, 16, 15, 17, 19, 18]
```

Each element in 'dif_list' is given by taking 3 numbers out of 'ex_list' and summing them up, i.e. 2+5+4 = 11, 2+5+6 = 13, 2+5+8 = 15, 2+4+6 = 12, etc.
Also for reference:

```
ex_list = [2,5,4,6,8]
another_list = partsum(ex_list, 4)
print(another_list) ==> [17, 19, 21, 20, 23]
```

Because 2+5+4+6 = 17, 2+5+4+8 = 19, etc.
Basically, partsum(thing, num) will take 'num' items of 'thing', sum them up, and append it to a new list. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's the larger context you need this for?

Comment: So you want all combinations with `num` elements and their sum?

Comment: If you are trying to find [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), using combinations is the least efficient way.

Comment: Are all of the numbers positive?

Answer (score 3):

You want [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20combinations#itertools.combinations).

```
import itertools

lst = [2,5,4,6,8]
combos = itertools.combinations(lst, 3)
# combos is equivalent to
# [ [2, 5, 4], [2, 5, 6], [2, 5, 8],
#   [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 8], [2, 6, 8],
#   [5, 4, 6], [5, 4, 8], [5, 6, 8],
#   [4, 6, 8] ]
result = [sum(combo) for combo in combos]
```

Comment: and if you want to only have distinct sums change the last line into `set([sum(combo) for combo in combos])`

Comment: @hansaplast Why not a set comprehension?

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks! And will this work if there are less than 3 items in a list 'lst' for combinations(lst,3)? (Or I can find out eventually...)

Comment: @adamsmith The program I'm using can't import `itertools`

Comment: @ChristopherMarley that's fine, write your own version then. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to import it though, it's part of the stdlib LOL!

Comment: Is there a way I can code a function that would do the same thing?

Comment: @AdamSmith could you recommend a starting place please, if possible? im fairly new to all the fanciness of python. thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherMarley I already linked the method in the module that does what you need. If you can't use the stdlib it means you're working on homework, which means you shouldn't be taking verbatim answers from the internet. Think deeply about the problem -- an inefficient algorithm isn't difficult to derive.